# Как закруглить углы у UITableViewCell (ячейки)

Tags: ios, swift

Как закруглить углы ячейки? Кто-нибудь делал? Может подскажете библиотеки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вроде так должно работать

```
cell.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Для любого наследника UIView можно в Interface Builder прописать следующим образом
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Решением будет использование `cornerRadius`, но я бы не рекомендовал применять его в самой ячейке, просто потому, что `contentView` - это служебная вьюха, плюс - она всегда растянута по высоте, то есть не удастся сделать промежутки между пузырями, которые, вероятно, скорее всего понадобятся из эстетических соображений. Вариант по-лучше - положить на `contentView` другую вьюху, и её уже закруглять. Если нужно просто создать видимость закругления, а не обрезать контент, то можно использовать UITableViewCell.backgroundView, а в неё уже положить UIImageView с правильно настроенным тайлингом.